# Django: Redirect to a page, then redirect back again?

Tags: django, httpresponse

As per the title: in Django views, can I redirect to a page using `HttpResponseRedirect` and then from that page, immediately redirect back again to the original page?

In other words, how can I get the second view to 'remember' the first one in order to redirect back there?

I want to do this to handle some LDAP authorisation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redirect to `/page2/?next=/page1/`, then get the original url from the GET parameters in the view for page2.

```
# page2 viewl
next = request.GET['next']
return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to avoid any session level logic. Your requirements have nothing to do with a session, so avoid using session level constructs.

You have a request level requirement, and the request level logic identified by Alasdair is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the original URL in a [session variable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), and then pop off that value and use it to redirect back to the original page.

Comment: Clever, I hadn't thought of that.